# Minimum number of bytes for view state in MyFaces server side state saving

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, myfaces, memory-consumption, state-saving

What is the minimum number of bytes for view state in MyFaces when server side state saving method is used?

Comment: a few... look at the source and see what kinds of variables are initialized when an empty viewState object is created. It probably depends on the JSF implementation to. And assumes you have an almost empty view.

Comment: would it matter if my state saving method is server? I guess if the state saving method is client then it sends the whole view as view state. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: if the state saving is server, only a token is sent. If it is client, only the "delta" state (JSF 2.0 PSS), or in other words , the changes since the first request.